# nesting preprocessor directives or other trickery to conditionally redefine the static keyword

Tags: c, unit-testing, c-preprocessor

I am using unity for unit testing.

I have a header throughout my project that I include with some helper macros, like an assert wrapper that I can use to track which assert fired.

In that header I also have the following definition:

```
#define static //nothing
```

I learned that little trick from this article: 
http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4007177/2/Doing-C-code-unit-testing-on-a-shoestring-Part-1-The-basics-and-the-tools

This allows me to write unit tests for static functions and it allows me to access any relevant file scope data from my test harness.

The trouble is this totally breaks static at the function scope. The article goes on to say if I do this:

```
#define static extern
```

Then any variable that is static at the function scope can then be defined within the test harness. We're off to the races, right? Not exactly.

Because the following occurs

```
void foo()
{
    extern bool my_flag = false;
}
```

Now we are supplying an initializer to declaration, which is invalid. So that means any static variable I handled this way would inherently need to be initialized after startup.

Because static variables within functions are relatively uncommon, I thought I might circumvent this by defining a new symbol, LOCAL_STATIC. So now in my header I have the following

```
#define static extern
#define LOCAL_STATIC static
```

But that does not work because those directives are evaluated strictly in order - `#define LOCAL_STATIC static` becomes `#define LOCAL_STATIC extern`, or at least that is what seems to be happening. Because LOCAL_STATIC produces the same error and indeed ends up getting changed to extern by the preprocessor.

So is there any way around this?

AFAIK anything like this is impossible:

```
#define LOCAL_STATIC  \
#undef static         \
static                \
#define static extern
```

The only thing I can think of is to leave static alone and define a new symbol, something like `HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE`.

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#define HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE extern
#else
#define HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE static
#endif
```

But that is going to clutter up the production code with this new weird thing "HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE". Static variables within functions are generally rare, but almost all static functions (except trivial helper functions) will need to be externally accessible by my test runner.

I've been trying to avoid writing a separate script that has to run before builds, but I am getting to that point now.

Comment: You really should **not** re`#define` C keywords. This is the road to (debugging) hell.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but redefining `static` seems like the most horrible idea ever, right on par with a coworker of mine who redefined `private` as `public` in our C++ codebase.

Comment: You will not get to the other side by digging a deeper hole. That first define is madness because you're breaking the language and causing a mess for anyone who'll ever debug this horror show. And making it more convoluted later will not make it better.

Comment: Please spare me the lectures, because this isn't production code. Generally speaking I would never redfined a keyword or a standard library macro or function as it is bad form and could be terribly confusing. But this something I am doing to make my code more testable for a unit test harness that is supposed to be as separate as possible from my production code.

Comment: @Nick: I think it would be reasonably readable if you spelled `HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE` as `STATIC` instead, but then you do have to be careful about not using `STATIC` inside function scope.

Comment: The idea of unit testing is to test **production code** _units_ (functions/modules/etc., depends on the definition of "unit"). If you change that code, the unit test is worth exactly **nothing**.

Comment: @Olaf I agree with you to a point but I think you are being dogmatic. Good design principles dictate that data and functions that do not need to be accessible outside of a module be encapsulated. However, in the spirit of writing granular small tests that are able to help localize defects the test harness needs access to some of those internal guts. Therefore the production code must change in a minimal way to be testable. So I want to make that change in an automated repeatable way using the preprocessor or an external script in one central place and document the behavior.

Comment: @rici That is a good suggestion. I'll probably do that for now in order to save time. Then maybe later I'll get fancier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea of creating a `HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE` macro is the cleanest way of going about this.  You definitely don't want to be #define-ing away `static` for just the reasons you described.

I don't think using this macro will be cluttering up your code.  You'll just be putting this in place of `static`, and it gives you the option of specifying exactly which functions you want to be able to unit test and keeping those minor utility functions explicitly `static`.

Comment: I shy away from that though, because it means most every function in an arbitrary C file will be like this `HARNESS_ACCESSIBLE void foo(void)`. To the person reading this in the code review or who is looking at the code later who is used to seeing static it might be frustrating. On the upside it would force him to be aware of the fact that unit testing is happening. But it seems to go against the spirit of unit testing being minimally invasive in the production code.

Comment: I am going to do this but use Rici's suggestion in the comments above and call it `STATIC` for now. Maybe later I'll write a python script that will strip out statics at the file scope and not the function.